# Un-Sharing OneNote

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote, onedrive, microsoft-onenote-2010

I had Onenote 2010 syncing to skydrive, but then I chose to "share" my onenote on a drive on my local computer, so that my wife could see it.  As a consequence of sharing it, the notebook was no longer synchronized to skydrive!  I was given no warning that sharing it locally would eliminate the cloud-sync capability.

As a choice of the two, I'd rather have it synced with the cloud rather than shared locally.  How do I "undo" what I've done?  It would also be nice to know how to get my cake and eat it too (sync with cloud AND share locally), but that is a low priority at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to recreate the notebook. In most cases, Onenote will leave the old copy of your notebook on the skydrive, so you can just pull down the old version and update the sections.  Otherwise, just create a new notebook and copy the old sections into that notebook.

Comment: In the future, if I wish to share the notebook with someone else, I presume I need to share it from the skydrive - rather than use the share options within onenote.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yup. Lest we wish to repeat history. . .